# I'm looking for the share of nudists per country

Tags: data-request, demographics, global

I'm looking for a dataset regarding the share of people who identify as naturists/nudists or have tried nudism per country, preferably as a CSV or JSON file or a spreadsheet but web scraping would work too.
Ideally this would include all the OECD countries but anything that includes at least one or 2 countries per continent (including South America) would work.
I don't need a specific license so anything is ok as long as I don't have to pay for it.
I'm not sure if this kind of data exists at all.